# How can I prevent R from leaking memory when concatenating data.tables?

Tags: r, memory-management, memory-leaks, data.table, rstudio-server

I am working with a list where each element is also a list, comprised of R `data.tables`. My task is to grab the *n*th element of each sublist, and then stack those `data.tables` into a larger `data.table`. So, from a list of twenty lists, each having twelve elements, I end up with a total list of twelve elements, where each element is a `data.table`.

I'm not having difficulty with the code to do this, but I am having some confusion about what is happening with R's memory management in this case. It is relatively simple to do the extraction, like this (just to show context, not a MWE on its own):

```
lst_new <- lapply(X = list_indices,
                  FUN = function(idx) {return(rbindlist(l = lapply(X = lst_old,FUN = `[[`,idx)))})
```

My question is, why is R not releasing the memory that was originally allocated to `lst_old` when I delete it? More generally, why is that my `rbind` operations seem to hold onto memory after the object is removed? Below is a minimal working example.

```
library(data.table)

# Create list elements of large enough size
uFunc_MakeElement <- function() {
    clicode <- paste(sample(x = c(letters,LETTERS),size = 4,replace = T),collapse = "")
    column_data <- replicate(n = 100,expr = {sample(x = c(0:20),size = 600000,replace = T)},simplify = FALSE)
    names(column_data) <- paste("var",1:100,sep = "")
    return(as.data.table(cbind(clicode = clicode,as.data.frame(column_data))))
}
lst_big <- replicate(n = 15,expr = uFunc_MakeElement(),simplify = FALSE)

# At this point, the rsession is consuming 4.01GB according to top (RES)
# According to RStudio, lst_big was 3.4Gb

# Transform to a data.table
dt_big <- rbindlist(l = lst_big)
# According to top, RES was 7.293Gb

rm(lst_big)
# RES does not change

dt_big <- rbind(dt_big,NULL)
# RES goes to 0.010t

gc()
# RES goes back down to 6.833Gb
```

I'm not sure why, when I remove `lst_big` after creating the new `data.table` using `rbindlist`, I am not having the memory returned to me. Even after manually calling `gc` (which you should not have to do), I still don't get back the memory that seems to be allocated to `lst_big`. Am I doing something wrong? Is there a better way to concatenate `data.tables` so that I do not leak memory?

(Tagging this with RStudio in case there's a chance it's somehow related to the IDE. This example is coming from RStudio Server running on an Ubuntu 14.04 box).

EDITED TO ADD: I just noticed that this memory usage issue remains even if I overwrite the list itself (rather than creating a new list, I just assign the output of my operations to the old list).

Comment: I see the first part (after rm lst_big), but the rbind does nothing (on R console).

Comment: @Frank that was just an experiment - I was curious if maybe updating it would somehow release something.

Comment: Oh ok, just reporting what I see, since apparently you did not test with R console.

Comment: Oh, just noticed that `rm(anything)` has no effect on RAM display in top (well, Windows system monitor) until I run `gc`. I read the likely explanation here in the FAQ: https://cran.r-project.org/doc/FAQ/R-FAQ.html#Why-is-R-apparently-not-releasing-memory_003f Not sure if that entirely covers what you're talking about, though.